# unable to edit cassandra user password

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I installed datastax cassandra enterprise version and its not allowing me to change the default password.

```
ALTER USER cassandra WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword' SUPERUSER ;
```

I am getting below error.

> Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Only superusers can create a role with superuser status"

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Aaron.

I am using Cassandra 3.10.0.1652 and  DSE 5.1.0

It worked after I enabled internal authentication in dse.yaml file

```
authentication_options:
 enabled: true
 default_scheme: internal

authorization_options:
 enabled: true

role_management_options:
 mode: internal
```

Thanks,
Ashwin.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are in cqlsh as the default cassandra/cassandra user, my guess is that it is tripping over logic designed to prevent giving "SUPERUSER" to yourself.  Try it without the "SUPERUSER" on the end:

Cassandra 2.1 or lower:

```
ALTER USER cassandra WITH PASSWORD 'new password';
```

Cassandra 2.2 or higher:

```
ALTER ROLE cassandra WITH PASSWORD='new password';
```